# Is $\dot x=0$ considered a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is $\dot x=0$ considered a differential equation? If so, is it the only possible differential equation where all real numbers are equilibrium points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and yes. A number is an equilibrium point if the evolution of the equation stays there, which means that $\dot{x}(p) = 0$ for all $p$.

Comment: What is understood by $\dot{x}(p) = 0$ ?

Comment: It's understood that $x$ is a function of $p$, and that its derivative at all points is 0. So $x(p) = c$ for some constant $c$.